# Javascript Height & Width Of Dropped Image

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, width

I have written code to access height width etc when image uploaded with a button but I cannot seem to access any information when the image is dropped. I am using sample code as below.

```
let uploadButton = document.getElementById("upload-button");
let chosenImage = document.getElementById("chosen-image");
let fileName = document.getElementById("file-name");
let container = document.querySelector(".container");
let error = document.getElementById("error");
let imageDisplay = document.getElementById("image-display");
const fileHandler = (file, name, type) => {
  if (type.split("/")[0] !== "image") {
    //File Type Error
    error.innerText = "Please upload an image file";
    return false;
  }
    
    
    
  error.innerText = "";
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  reader.onloadend = () => {
    //image and file name
    let imageContainer = document.createElement("figure");
    let img = document.createElement("img");
      
    img.src = reader.result;
    imageContainer.appendChild(img);
    imageContainer.innerHTML += `<figcaption>${name}</figcaption>`;
    imageDisplay.appendChild(imageContainer);
  };
};

//Upload Button
uploadButton.addEventListener("change", () => {
  imageDisplay.innerHTML = "";
  Array.from(uploadButton.files).forEach((file) => {
    fileHandler(file, file.name, file.type);
  });
});

container.addEventListener(
  "dragenter",
  (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    container.classList.add("active");
  },
  false
);

container.addEventListener(
  "dragleave",
  (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    container.classList.remove("active");
  },
  false
);

container.addEventListener(
  "dragover",
  (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    container.classList.add("active");
  },
  false
);



container.addEventListener(
  "drop",
  (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    container.classList.remove("active");
    let draggedData = e.dataTransfer;
    let files = draggedData.files;
    imageDisplay.innerHTML = "";
    Array.from(files).forEach((file) => {
      fileHandler(file, file.name, file.type);
    });
      
  },

  false
);

window.onload = () => {
  error.innerText = "";
};`
```

All I seem to be able to gather is the image source (base64) img.src = reader.result;
I have looked at different methods on stackoverflow, however they don't seem to fit with this particular code.

I have been at this for three days.

Comment: in your `Array.from(files).forEach((file)·=>·{` function, put a `console.dir(file)` call and see what methods/properties does the `file` have. Probably there is something, which might be helpful

Comment: I tried it and nothing happened at all. Doesn't show anything as in no action.

Comment: I can grab a hold of a physically uploaded item with " var item = document.querySelector('#upload-button').files[0];" Then can get width and height easily  I just cannot find a way to grab hold of a dropped item so I can process it in the same way.

Comment: then you must've done it in the wrong location. You have several occurrences of `Array.from` you need the drop handler.

Comment: Solved it at last :  I added the section marked "try2"                                                  let reader = new FileReader();
 
 //try2
 reader.onload = function() {
    var image = new Image();

    image.src = reader.result;

    image.onload = function() {
   imageWidth = image.width;
   imageHeight =image.height;
    };

};
 
 //try2 end

Comment: The problem is now solved however : your console  suggestion puts the console element inside of the array and it cannot possibly report unless it is thereafter extracted from the array.